# C++ how to identify unsigned types?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I want to write an absolute value function for every type.
Something like:

```
template <class T>
T MyAbsVersion(T num)
{
    return (num > 0) ? num : num*-1;
}
```

However, I'd like to decline numbers of type unsigned.
Any good way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: [`std::is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned). You can use that with `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [*`std::is_signed`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) to accept numbers of only `signed` type

```
template<class T ,
          typename std::enable_if< std::is_signed<T>::value  >::type* = nullptr >
T myabs(T num) 
{
    return (num > 0) ? num : num*-1;
}
```

Demo [*`Here`*](http://rextester.com/YDLB81527)

Comment: That should *allow* unsigned values, no?

Comment: How come the code in the example don't compile and your demo does?

Comment: @AviHarush it does compile.

Comment: @AviHarush See [this](http://rextester.com/CIJQP76783) , I used `using` in previous demo, to make it clean

Comment: Strange, It won't compile at my VS2013. The error is "No instance of myabs matches your argument list."

Comment: I'll check my settings. Thanks!